# Madcap Flare JavaScript method, open the help document is new window instead of a new tab

Tags: javascript, flare, madcap

While integrating the Flare application, I am trying to use the JavaScript method. The below is the approach suggested.
While I am using this I am always getting the document opened in a new tab instead of a new window. Is there any approach in JS so that I can open this in a new window rather than a new tab.

Reference: http://webhelp.madcapsoftware.com/flare11/Content/CSH/HTML5_CSH_Calls/CSH_Calls_HTML5_Developers.htm?Highlight=developers

```
<input type="button" value="Open Help System" onclick="MadCap.OpenHelp(ID, skin name, search string, first pick search string value );" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a browser configuration.  A new tab "is" a new window. It's just organized nicely for you.

you can make a popup though.  look at jquery ui dialogs: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But, I need to open it in a new pop-up window of some fixed size (width:300px, height:600px).

Comment: @ArunPati well you can put it in an iframe, make a nice frame for it, and makeit centered on the current window. that's the best you'll be able to do

Answer (score 0):

The skin name specifies the target window object.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after, it is important to understand the different elements you can use when you make the JS call -- and this is not an easy thing to understand from the documentation.

```
onclick="MadCap.OpenHelp(ID, skin name, search string, first pick search string value );"
```

The `ID` is the CSH ID that you assigned in the alias editor in Flare. This can either be the ID or the value (which is odd, but true).

The `skin name` is the filename of the skin you want to include, but NOT the extension. So if in your project you have a `my html5 skin.flskn` file, you would enter: `my html5 skin`. (Please don't use spaces in your skin names... but they don't actually affect the functionality in this case.)

So if you want to create a link to a topic that has a CSHID of 1234, and you want to use the default skin tied to the target, you would use:

```
onclick="MadCap.OpenHelp(1234);"
```

If you want to create a link to a topic that has a CSHID of 1234, and you want to use the skin specialskin.flskn, you would use:

```
onclick="MadCap.OpenHelp(1234,specialskin);"
```

I hope this clarifies the situation for somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What skin were you using? You can only control the size of the output window in HTML5 Tripane output (not topnav or sidenav).

https://help.madcapsoftware.com/flare2022r3/Content/Flare/Skins/Other-Activities/General/Specifying-Size-Positioning-Output-Window.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."